# What was Beauvoirs example of meaningless freedom involving a harem?

Tags: existentialism, sartre

I am looking up sources on Simone de Beauvoir's account of freedom and found this in an old issue of a philosophy magazine:

> She had argued with him that freedom of any sort was pretty
> meaningless for a woman imprisoned in a harem. Sartre had succeeded in
> overcoming her doubts [...]

What is the source of this argument? I am also specifically looking for Sartre's counterargument.

Note: It is not her *The Ethics of Ambiguity*.

Answer (score 1):

Simone de Beauvoir, *La Force de l’âge*, Paris, Gallimard, « Folio », 1999, p.498-499

> I argued that from the standpoint of freedom, as Sartre defined it -
> not stoic resignation but active going beyond the given - the
> situations are not equivalent: what going beyond is possible for the
> woman locked in a harem? Even this confinement, there are different
> ways of living it, Sartre told me. I persisted for a long time and
> only gave in half-heartedly. Deep down, I was right. But to defend >my position, I would have had to abandon the terrain of individual
> morality, therefore idealistic, on which we were placed.

(google translation of : Je soutenais que, du point de vue de la liberté, telle que Sartre la définissait - non pas résignation stoïque mais  dépassement actif du donné - les situations ne sont pas équivalentes : quel dépassement est possible à la femme  enfermée dans un harem ? Même cette claustration, il y a différentes manières de la vivre, me disait Sartre. Je  m’obstinai  longtemps  et  je  ne  cédai  que  du  bout  des  lèvres. Au  fond,  j’avais  raison.  Mais  pour  défendre  ma position,  il  m’aurait  fallu  abandonner  le  terrain  de  la  morale  individuelle,  donc  idéaliste,  sur  lequel  nous  nous placions.)